# my view.hidden does not work in iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios

My `view.hidden` doesn't work in iphone 4 but its ok in Iphone 4S. I tried in both devices with IOS 6.1.3
in my code I've 2 views one  top of the other, when first view its opened the other view has atribute hidden is YES beacuse when I active the first view's button change the atribute hidden from second view but the second vew didn't appeared and the the press button event this sucesed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first view is obscuring the second view, second view will not appear irrespective of hidden = YES or NO.

Check your view hierarchy from storyboard or xib.

Comment: hi, seems that my code is not updated in the iphone 4, the changes you made in the storyboard are not reflected in the iphone 4 but its ok in Iphone 4S

Comment: seems weird are you sure your app is updated on both devices?

Comment: only now I have the iphone 4 and the simulator

Comment: i make changes in the storyboard are not reflected in the iphone but if the simulator

Comment: how exactly do you debug on device? Is it directly connected or some other means? My experience still tells me you have not updated the build on 4S device.

Comment: connect your phone to your mac and compile with Xcode for viewing on the iPhone,code changes if they work but not in the storyboard

Comment: thanks, was solved by renaming the storyboard

Comment: Glad to help. Happened with me too!